# The party caused a mess in the common area. The school asked us "to do the party elsewhere next time." - does this make sense?

Tags: meaning, time

**Example 1**

> The party caused a mess in the common area. The school asked us to **do the party elsewhere next time.**

Even though the word "ask" is past tense, what the school asked for (the part in bold) is in the future and has not happened yet. Does this example make sense?

Comment: The verb tense is fine, though I would use _have_ or _hold_ rather than _do_.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference that what the school asked for is in the future - they asked us ***to do*** something, which requires an infinitive verb in the complement of the main verb ***asked***. Compare *Yesterday they asked us **to be** quiet. Today they're asking us **to be** tidy*.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. You use "asked" in the past tense since the request happened in the past.

The grammar of the verb "ask" is "ask to *infinitive*". Infinitive verbs never have any tense. So it is "asked to do" or "is asking to do" or "will ask to do".  The verb "do" never changes.

But you would normally "*hold* a party", not "do a party".